# Anybody has any ideas what exactly spWeb.Features.Add does?

Tags: sharepoint, addition

anybody know what exactly below code does?

`SPWeb.Features.Add(Guid, bool)`

Does it use the .xmls in Template\Features\<-myFeature-> to **install** the feature and **activate** it? Or just activate it? Or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you specified activates feature with specified id on specified SPWeb object. It does not install it. Here is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465255.aspx) link.

It actually uses xml files in "Template\Features\<-myFeature->" folder when you activate feature. 
But if you change file in this folder you won't see any effect momentary because this files are cached. After changing files in feature folder you need to do iisreset and then activate feature in order to see the difference.